# How to use orderBy with include in sequelizejs

Tags: include, sql-order-by, sequelize.js, distance

I'm trying to fetch result with a column which is calculated at run time in query and alias with name

> distance

here is my query

```
User.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Address,
        attributes: ['col1',
          [Sequelize.literal("6371  acos(cos(radians(122))  cos(radians(latitude))  cos(radians(122) - radians(longitude)) + sin(radians(6661))  sin(radians(latitude)))"), 'distance']
        ],
      }],
      order: [Sequelize.literal("Address.distance"), 'DESC']
    });
```

but it returns a error

> unknown column Address.distance

I also tried this

```
User.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Address,
        attributes: ['col1',
          [Sequelize.literal("6371  acos(cos(radians(122))  cos(radians(latitude))  cos(radians(122) - radians(longitude)) + sin(radians(6661))  sin(radians(latitude)))"), 'distance']
        ],
      }],
      order: ["distance", 'DESC']
    });
```

but it gave same error :

> unknown column distance

Can anyone help in this matter.
Thanks in advance

Comment: user model table doesn't have distance column. where is your model definition?

Comment: Yes Model table doesn't have 'distance' column, it just calculate lat and long so I alias the new calculated column as 'distance'.

`attributes: ['col1',
          [Sequelize.literal("6371  acos(cos(radians(122))  cos(radians(latitude))  cos(radians(122) - radians(longitude)) + sin(radians(6661))  sin(radians(latitude)))"), 'distance']
        ]`
here I just calculate and alias it as **distance**

Comment: i also has this problem and got no solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly specify the model by which you want to sort.

```
User.findAll({
      ...
      order: [ [ Address, 'distance', 'DESC' ] ]
    });
```

Comment: I tried
But **distance** doesn't belongs to **Address** model I calculate lat lng on in query and alias it as **distance**

Answer (score 0):

you can Order by distance after distance describe in attributes

```js
order: [[Sequelize.literal("distance"), "asc"]],
```